# Azure portal, this asset was not found

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've spotted a number of resources on my Azure portal that have what looks like a GUID for a name. When i click on the resource to see the overview i get a message that says "This asset was not found, it may have been deleted".
The type is Microsoft.Web/certificate. Are these resources that have failed to be deleted, is this something i should be worried about?

[image: Message displayed]
[image: Asset view]

Comment: well, if you didn't try to delete them and they are deleted - you probably should be worried... on the other hand, did you try refreshing your browser? cleaning cookies? does the problem persist?

Comment: Just to clarify, the subscription is used to host a number of different resources for my company and is administer by a handful of IT staff. We've recently retired a number of old websites and launched their replacements. It's not going away with refreshing the browsers as i initially spotted them a week ago.